# Get JSON values numerically in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to have my Javascript call my JSON (shown below) so that I can access it in a while loop, like this:
v[0].title;

Basically, I want to know how to loop through each value from bottom to top and insert it into my html.

```
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var vt = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                while (document.getElementsByClassName("box-head") != vt.sux27.title) {
                
                                
                                document.getElementsByClassName("box-href")[i].href = vt.sux27.link;
                                document.getElementsByClassName("box-img")[i].src = vt.sux27.img;
                                document.getElementsByClassName("box-cat")[i].innerHTML = vt.sux27.categories[1];
                                document.getElementsByClassName("box-head")[i].innerHTML = vt.sux27.title;
                                document.getElementsByClassName("box-desc")[i].innerHTML = vt.sux27.description;                                
                                document.getElementsByClassName("box-likes")[i].innerHTML = vt.sux27.rating;
                                document.getElementsByClassName("box-author")[i].innerHTML = vt.sux27.author_name;
                                document.getElementsByClassName("box-author")[i].href = vt.sux27.author_link;
                        i++;
                        
                }               
        }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://www.global.cf/website-frontend/articles/articles.json", true);
  xhttp.send();
```

Here is my json:

```
{
    "sux27": {
        "img":"https://placecorgi.com/320/240", "categories" : ["#nature", "#pets"], "title" : "Best corgis to get", "description" : "This article  contains a cute corgi These dogs are extremely hardy, and will kill without hesistation...", "link" : "https://www.global.cf", "rating" : 27, "author_name" : "Pex co", "author_link" : "www.pex.com"
    },
    "cat": {
        "img":"http://placekitten.com/320/240", "categories" : ["#pets", "#gross"], "title" : "Cats up the wazzou", "description" : "Do you love dirty yet found cute by some, yet spread desease? Get a cat! This is totaly for u", "link" : "pets.com/pets", "rating" : 0, "author_name" : "Pets.com", "author_link" : "pets.com"
    }

}
```

Comment: So your question is about, how to loop through a object?

Comment: Seems like a solid question to me @Prana

Comment: See my answer below. Reason for the down votes may be your question title. That is irrelevant to your question

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to loop through a object, you can use `Object.keys` to convert it into arrray and then you can use array iteration methods.

```
Object.keys(vt).forEach( (item, id) => {
   // here item will equal to each key in the object
   document.getElementsByClassName("box-href")[id].href = vt[item].link
   // you can continue doing this for your rest of the elements
})
```

Comment: Hi! So from here, how would I iterate through each "item" AKA object in the JSON? Should I create a new question to answer this? @Prana